# NHibernate HasMany с коллекцией Id

Tags: c#, nhibernate

Нужно настроить маппинг на коллекцию Id в модели.

В случае со связью 1 к 1, все предельно ясно. Я делаю так

```
References(myEntity => myEntity.Prop).Column("my_entity_id").ReadOnly();
Map(myEntity => myEntity.PropId).Column("my_entity_id");
```

Это означает, что у меня в сущности MyEntity есть ссылка на сущность Prop, а поле PropId является идентификатором этой сущности и именно через него я меняю связанную сущность Prop на другую.

А как сделать такое же поведение для коллекций?

```
HasMany(myEntity => myEntity.OtherProperties).KeyColumn("my_entity_id");
```

Укажет, что у сущности OtherProperty есть связь с MyEntity, но для того, чтобы указать какие сущности OtherProperty связаны с текущей MyEntity (в контексте MyEntity) мне бы хотелось иметь в ней свойство OtherPropertiesIdList и работать с ней. Но как настроить маппинг?

Comment: ManyToMany надо что ли? Оно не делается напрямую, нужно завести промежуточную коллекцию, которая будет эту связь хранить.

Comment: Мне нужно иметь в модели коллекцию идентификаторов связанных сущностей. Не имеет значения, many to many это или has many.

Comment: По моему, вы делаете что-то не так. Зачем отдельно хранить Id - это первый вопрос. Второй - с чего вы взяли, что Map и References делают одно и то же? https://github.com/FluentNHibernate/fluent-nhibernate/wiki/Fluent-mapping мап для свойств, референсы - для обратной связи с коллекцией. По вашему вопросу - сделайте просто коллекцию типа ваших Id и пользуйтесь.

Comment: @Monk, я нигде и не писал что Map и Reference делают одно и то же. Именно коллекцию типа Id я и хочу сделать, но как? То есть мне надо, чтобы эта коллекция заполнялась данными при выборке и использовалась при обновлении/добавлении данных

Comment: А работает двойной такой маппинг Prop хотя бы? Потому что я и его повторить не смог - в базе Id лежит, а вот ссылка на сущность не заполняется на загрузке.

Comment: @Monk, работает. Просто на сущность не маппинг настраивается, а референс. Там в вопросе в самом есть пример, как это делается.

Comment: Так я и повторил код из вопроса. Id из базы загружается и заполняется, а вот свойство на сущность - остается null.

Comment: @Monk, это потому что ленивая загрузка. Вложенную сущность надо подтянуть, пока открыт контекст